# Selecting a specific value in VBA Excel to Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm having problems to specify a value to start adding fields to my table, i need to insert all the values with the condition of this specific value in the MOD_CODE column from Excel to be inserted in this way to Access.

```
.Fields("MOD_CODE") = Sheets(wsName).Cells(iX, 2).Value
```

It inserts all the fields correctly from Excel to Access but i can not make that picks a specific value in this field

```
Dim Conn As ADODB.Connection, RecSet As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fila As Long, primerFila As Integer, ultimaFila As Long, iX As Long
Dim dataSource As String, Tabla As String
Dim wsName As String
Dim rFound As Range
dataSource = Sheets("parametros").[B1]
Tabla = Sheets("parametros").[B2]
wsName = Sheets("parametros").[B3]
primerFila = Sheets("parametros").[B4]

Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " & dataSource & ";"
'Conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= " & dataSource & ";"

Set RecSet = New ADODB.Recordset
RecSet.Open Tabla, Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
ultimaFila = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(wsName).Range("A:A"))
For iX = primerFila To ultimaFila


With RecSet
.AddNew
.Fields("PLANT") = Sheets(wsName).Cells(iX, 1).Value
.Fields("MOD_CODE") = Sheets(wsName).Cells(iX, 2).Value
.Fields("BOM_KEY") = Sheets(wsName).Cells(iX, 3).Value
.Fields("ASSY_ADDRESS") = Sheets(wsName).Cells(iX, 4).Value
.Update

End With

Next iX
RecSet.Close
Set RecSet = Nothing
Conn.Close
Set Conn = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: What is your *actual problem statement*?  What do you mean by  "picks a specific value in this field"?

Comment: What is the data type in the "MOD_CODE" field? and what type of data are you trying to pass into it? This could be the issue, but hard to say without knowing what error you get when you try to update the recordset.

Comment: My data inserted needs to be related to an specif field in my Excel sheet, in this case my sheet has a value like this one "808C" in the B column that is related with this part of the code

Comment: I need to make a kind of filter i think, i'm new at VBA